# Images not showing after an ajax call to get content

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, image

I have a modal that shows content pulled via an ajax call. In this content there is an image slider. The slider works and the images have loaded but they still do not show. Only when I hit f12 to use firebug to try and find out if the images are loaded do the images show on the page.  This only happens if firebug is not detached from the browser. It's almost as though they need a kick to show on the page.

I'm using Foundation 4 reveal for the modal

I've searched for a similar problem but can't seem to find anything out there. #
How do I get the images to show after the content has been added to the #popout div.

My code is below

```
(function($) {
    $('.rslides li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var project_id = $('.rslides1_on .popout-link').data('project-id');
        var url = '/popout-content.php?aid=' + project_id;

        params = {
            aid: project_id
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'popout-content.php',
            data: params,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {

                if (html != 'empty') {
                    $('#popout').foundation('reveal', 'open');
                    $('#popout').html(html);
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: do you have a live link or better yet, recreate this problem in jsfiddle, plus if you have the latest jQuery running use `.done` instead of success

Comment: Try to load html content in your modal first and then show modal, it seems when you are showing modal the html is not yet loaded in modal and hence its not shown.

Comment: Got it resolved. There was height set to 0 on a parent element by the slider plugin Doh!